# Highchart tooltip formatter function not able to get x value (this.x)?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I was try to using formatter function with new angular 12 i was getting error Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ChartService'.ts(2339) how to fix that ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIli9.png)

Comment: Can you share the entire ChartService.ts file? In order to help I need to know what variables are declared...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please explain more the scope of `value`

if `value` set from service or api response you can try `this['value']` and test in runtime

Answer (score 0):

You have missing types for formatter callback function, for test I set type at any and value is show without problems.

In our wrapper documentation you will find an example that explained how to add missing type (property XXX does not exist on type YYY to add missing types).

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-4sokbv

Documentation:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#online-examples